# are sensing power supplies and switching power supplies the same thing?

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply

What is the difference between sensing power supplies and switching power supplies? Are they the same thing?

Comment: Question can easily be answered with Google. Should be closed - insufficient research.

Comment: Sensing and switching have no relation to each other except that both words start with an S. All regulated power supplies are Sensing in the Sense that they measure (sense) their output and control it by a feedback loop. Switching is a power efficient way of doing this regulation but has no relation to the sensing itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Sensing" power supplies are generally referred to as "remote sensing power supplies" and are used to good advantage when the load is some distance away from the supply.

The way the advantage works is that a separate pair of wires is brought back from across the load to the supply, and circuitry in the supply adjusts the supply's output voltage to that voltage required to overcome the resistance of the primary wiring to the load and keep the load voltage constant.

The connection is called a "Kelvin connection" and the sense wiring can be very small diameter since it's only carrying a very low current, the sensing circuitry being a highish impedance.

So, to answer your question, it's possible for a switching supply and a linear supply to both be [remote] sensing supplies, although a switching supply and a linear supply are quite different beasties otherwise.